# Excel: How to transform multiple columns with headers into 2 columns, one for the data, one for the header

Tags: excel, list, powerquery, transpose, m

I have a table of products, with multiple QTYs by month. How do I convert this table into a 2-columns list - one for QTY, one for month.

Source Data:

```
Product | 2019-06 | 2019-07 | 2019-08 | 2019-09 | 2019-10
----------------------------------------------------------
Apple   |   10    |   10    |   20    |   25    |   10
Orange  |   50    |   100   |   75    |   50    |   100
```

Desired Output:

```
Product | QTY | Date
---------------------
Apple   |  10 | 2019-06
Apple   |  10 | 2019-07
Apple   |  20 | 2019-08
Apple   |  25 | 2019-09
Apple   |  10 | 2019-10
Orange  |  50 | 2019-06
Orange  | 100 | 2019-07
Orange  |  75 | 2019-08
Orange  |  50 | 2019-09
Orange  | 100 | 2019-10
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal

Answer (score 2):

Use `Power Query`  a free MS add-in since 2010, and distributed with Excel 2016+ as `Get&Transform`.

In the Power Query UI, select the first column and then Unpivot other columns. Rename the columns as needed.

Also see my answer to [Resorting Table using Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504074/resorting-table-using-array) for more details

[image]